# LSTM Keras target size error

Tags: python, keras, lstm

```
#x_train.shape = 7x5x5 numpy array
#y_train.shape = 3x5x5 numpy array
#x_test.shape = (7,) numpy array
#y_test.shape = (3,)  numpy array I have binary output as 0 or 1.
timeteps = 5
data_dim = 5

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=`(timesteps,data_dim)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=1)
score = model.evaluate(X_test,y_test,batch_size=1)
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 5, 5)
```

I am trying to model LSTM using random data and this error occurs. I have tried many things but I could not succeed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What other things have you tried? How about adding a `Flatten()` layer between the last `LSTM` and the `Dense` layer?

Comment: @DexterMorgan flatten has little use here and is not intended for sequential data, but more often used for CNNs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems/misunderstands here?

You can see that your y is actually 3 dimensional. However, the last lstm layer, you have return sequences as false, meaning that the LSTM is returning a single 32 long vector and sending that into the dense layer.

Furthermore, the use of multiple LSTMS here seems to lack purpose, though it does not necessarily harm anything.

In order to fit your presumed data, you would want the last lstm to have `return_sequences` as `True`, and have the number of neurons in that lstm not 32, but rather 5, as in the final dimension of your y data.

You could also not have it at all (since you already have two lstms before that, and instead make the second lstm only have 5 neurons and have the final lstm layer be removed entirely. You would then use a time distributed wrapper on the last dense layer

```
model.add(TimeDistrubuted(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')))
```

which says to apply the same dense layer to every timestep of the data, which is required by the shape of your y data.